# JasperReport custom DefaultParametersForm.jsp

Tags: jsp, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've managed to provide a custom template and override the default controls I setup in the repository specific to this report.

However for the life of me I cannot find any examples of how I might start adding controls. Preferably by calling a render() with a reference to the control ID I configured through the interface. I have the form as I need it but need to tweak two custom elements on the form - this seems to be the best approach.

Having googled to the ends of the earth...does anyone know or care to show me what the code would look like to say render one of the SELECT controls in my custom JSP file?

I have a SELECT bound to a SQL query that shows all the customers...ID_CUSTOMER - if I could find a tutorial that demonstrated how this is done that would be awesome.

Apprently that is explained in the ultimate guide but version 4.0 is not free.

Comment: Are you talking about JR Server?

Comment: Yes I believe so JR Server...particularly the backend control panel. I have a report or two which I am trying to provide a basic interactive interface too using Input Controls but need a bit more flexibility...short of building an entire web interface myself I'd rather piggy back on JR.